# Is it possible to vectorize the documents using Google BERT?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, doc2vec, bert-language-model

I would like to convert my documents to vector using BERT, one vector for each document. Is it possible? How could it be programmed using standard or popular libraries?

Comment: It is not a programming questions, try to ask it on https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes. Use Bert-as-service

Comment: @SamH.Thanks for your response, can you please explain a little bit? As far as I know, Bert-as-service encodes each sentence to a fixed-length vector. I need to create a vector for each document.

Comment: Could you please clarify about what you mean by 'document' in this case?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa: By document I mean a text with multiple paragraphs.

Comment: pre-trained BERT has constraints on sequence length of 512 word-piece tokens. If your document length is less than that, you can.